# How do I trim whitespace from the output I capture with backticks in Perl?

Tags: perl, whitespace

I'm capturing some output from an external program:

```
  my $cmd = "grep -h $text $file2 $file1 | tail -1 | awk '{print \$NF }' ";
  my $port_number;
  $port_number =`$cmd`;

  print "port No : ==$port_number==";
```

The output has extra whitespace around the port number:

```
port No : == 2323

==
```

and I tried [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/function/chomp.html) but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide the code with the chomp. What do you mean by "its not working"?  You've been on this site long enough to know how to ask a question properly.

Comment: ACtually the issue is : the port_no variable  has backword characters and the output is overwritting .

Comment: What is a "backword" character? Can you show use a hex repesentation of the string that you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your problems is that you don't need to use any external commands to do what you are doing. Stay inside Perl, which has the regex, file handling, and awk features built in:

```
my $last_matching_line;
{
local @ARGV = ( $file2, $file1 );

while( <> )
    {
    next unless /$text/;
    $last_matching_line = $_;
    }
}

my( $port_number ) = ( split /\s+/, $last_matching_line)[-1];

print "port No : ==$port_number==";
```

Answer (score 6):

from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html): "You can actually chomp anything that's an lvalue, including an assignment:"

So you want:

```
chomp($port_number =`$cmd`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can strip all whitespace with this:

```
$port_number =~ s/\s+//g;
```

Comment: @joe: ...which you still did not clearly state.  Help others so that they can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try to read your mind here and figure out what you mean by "its not working", by pointing you at the documentation for [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

> This safer version of "chop" removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of $/ (also known as $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR in
>   the "English" module).  **It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments**.

To use it correctly (assuming you want the rest of the string, not the newline), don't take its return value:

```
my $port = `$cmd`;
chomp $port;
print "$port\n";
```

You can remove any undesired surrounding whitespace with `trim` in the core module [String::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/String::Util):

```
use String::Util 'trim';
trim $port;
```

Comment: `String::Util` is not a core module. If we are going to install a CPAN module, we might as well use the one that does the job the best: `String::Strip`. See http://www.illusori.co.uk/perl/2010/03/05/advanced_benchmark_analysis_1.html

Comment: @daxim: Module::CoreList tells me that String::Util has been in perl since 5.00x; perhaps I'm interpreting its results incorrectly.

Comment: You are mistaken: `Scalar::Util` ≠ `String::Util`

Answer (score -1):

`chomp` only removes the last linebreak. Try a regex like this:

```
s/(?:\r?\n)*$//
```

Comment: In Perl 5.10 of later, you can use the `\R` character class that matches generalized line endings. That would then be `s/\R+\z//;`

Comment: Sweet, didn't now that one. But I guess it's better to be one the safe side since 5.8 is still pretty popular.